# Equal height rows in a CSS grid

Tags: css, grid-layout

I am using a simple grid framework (http://www.modestgrid.com/), with a fixed number of rows. Is there any easy way to make all of the rows the same height, without specifying the height of the `.row` class as a percent?

My row class for 6 rows looks like this:

```
.row {
    height: 16.666%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.row:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Is there any way to not have to specify the `height: 16.666%;` and have CSS automatically make all the rows the same height and have them vertically fill their container element?

I suppose that I could use a `<table>` or JavaScript to accomplish this, but I was hoping for a pure CSS solution. I need to support IE10 and all of the latest other common browsers.

Comment: Look for `flexbox`.

Comment: I do not believe that I can use that in IE10.

Comment: IE10 is the first version that supports Flexbox. I do not know if it has bugs though, most probably.

Comment: IE === bugs :-)

Comment: What about CSS attribute "display:table"?

Comment: I believe even with IE10 bugs and having to use the 2012 Syntax, you should be able to accomplish what you want with flexbox. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox - Check out the notes and known issues section. note: I could be wrong :)

Comment: I played with the flexbox stuff. Is it possible to force the rows to stretch? They were equally spaced, but the items were squashed to the top of each row instead of being stretched out to 100%. I even tried `align-items: stretch;`, which I believe is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **display: table.**

[It's supported in IE8+ and has a decent support in other browsers as well.](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.row:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      Row 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution without modest grid: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0wc4wn4/1/)

Solution with modest grid: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0wc4wn4/)